# pyinstaller is not attaching my image when I create an executable

Tags: python, tkinter

How can i make an executable that can load image, and that my friends don't depend on downloading the executable and image or a heavy folder?
I'm trying to create an executable for my python program, but when I try to open its executable, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 49, in <module>
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4103, in __init__
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4048, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "logo.png": no such file or directory
```

The code I'm using to compile is this:

> pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --add-data "logo.png;." main.py

Is there any other compilation method or other way to make an executable with the logo attached? I tried some methods like:

```
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

But to no avail, and my complete code is this:

```
from pytube import Playlist, YouTube
from tkinter import *
from moviepy import *
import os
import re

if os.name == "nt":
    downfolder = f"{os.getenv('USERPROFILE')}\\Downloads"
else:
    downfolder = f"{os.getenv('HOME')}/Downloads"

def playlist_audio():
    get_link = link_field.get()
    p = Playlist(get_link)
    p._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")
    for video in p.videos:
     screen.title('downloading.')
     mp3_audio = video.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(downfolder)
     audioconvert(mp3_audio)
             
    #
    screen.title('completed')

def video_mp3():
    get_link = link_field.get()
    screen.title('downloading.')
    mp3_audio = YouTube(get_link).streams.filter(only_audio=True).first().download(downfolder)
    audioconvert(mp3_audio)

    #
    screen.title('completed')

def audioconvert(mp3_audio):
   try:
     base, ext = os.path.splitext(mp3_audio)
     new_file = base + '.mp3'
     os.rename(mp3_audio , new_file)
   except WindowsError:
     os.remove(new_file)
     os.rename(mp3_audio , new_file)

screen = Tk()
title = screen.title('Python mp3')
screen.resizable(False, False)
Canvas = Canvas(screen, width=400, height=200)
Canvas.pack()

logoimg = PhotoImage(file='logo.png')
logo_img = logoimg.subsample(2, 2)
Canvas.create_image(215, 25, image=logo_img)

link_field = Entry(screen, width=50)
link_label = Label(screen, text="Enter the song/playlist URL.")

Canvas.create_window(200, 90, window=link_field)
Canvas.create_window(200, 70, window=link_label)

def convert():
  try:
      video_mp3()
      return True
  except:
      screen.title("wait a few seconds")

  try:
      playlist_audio()
      return False
  except:
      screen.title("unknown error, try again")

download = Button(screen, text="download", bg='green', padx='20', pady='5',font=('Arial', 12), fg='#fff', command=convert)
Canvas.create_window(200, 140, window=download)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't you need an `.ico` file and not `.png` for that? Pretty sure the syntax is `-i "file.ico"` for windows.

Comment: Do you mean `--add-data` instead of `--app-data` when running `pyinstaller`?

Comment: the logo.png is not for the program icon, it is an image that goes inside the program, sorry for the "app-data" but yes I meant "add-data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work.

In your python code add this to access your image from the MEI directory

```
photopath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logo.png')
logoimg = PhotoImage(file=photopath)
```

Here are the steps I took.

1. create empty folder; `cd` into it; copy the logo.png an script(`main.py`)
2. `py -m venv venv && venv\Scripts\activate`
3. `py -m pip install --upgrade pip pyinstaller moviepy pytube`
4. `pyinstaller -F main.py`
5. Then in the spec file add on line 11 (i think) edit `datas=[('logo.png','.')],`

You can make other adjustments in the spec file as well like setting `console=False` for it to work in windowed mode and changing the name of the output executable file and other stuff.

6. `pyinstaller main.spec`

Thats it... the executable should work fine and load your photo and all.